# Determine which file has an error when running YUI compressor from Ant

Tags: ant, jenkins, yui-compressor

We compress our javascript (and css files) with YUI compressor during our ant build task running on our Jenkins CI Server.  However, it is very difficult to determine which js files YUI compressor is having errors with.  We see a bunch of things like:

```
[minify-js] [ERROR] 3:35:unterminated string literal
[minify-js] 
[minify-js] [ERROR] 3:35:syntax error
[minify-js] 
[minify-js] [ERROR] 4:8:syntax error
[minify-js] 
[minify-js] [ERROR] 1:0:Compilation produced 3 syntax errors.
[minify-js] org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Compilation produced 3 syntax errors.
[minify-js]     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor$1.runtimeError(YUICompressor.java:135)
[minify-js]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:410)
[minify-js]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:355)
[minify-js]     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
[minify-js]     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
[minify-js]     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:112)
[minify-js]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[minify-js]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[minify-js]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[minify-js]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[minify-js]     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:20)
[minify-js] Result: 2
```

in the output, but I have no idea which of the hundreds of JS files the error is coming from.  Our ant task looks like:

```
<target name="minify-js">
    <apply executable="yuicompressor" parallel="false" dest="${global.dir}/" taskname="minify-js" force="true">
        <fileset dir="${global.dir}/" includes="**/*.js">
            <exclude name="*.min.js" />
        </fileset>
        <arg value="--type=js" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg value="-o" />
        <targetfile />
        <mapper type="identity" />
    </apply>
</target>
```

Not being an expert on Ant or YUI compressor, is there something we can do so that the filename where there error is happening is output somewhere?

Comment: i got a same issue. The jenkins build is getting failed when the js files contains any syntax error. Is there any way to output the files that are having errors and skip those file, so that the build wont get failed.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how the yuicompressor works, I assume that it works on one file at a time.

If this is true, you can do it with [for from ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html). You would need to install [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net) prior.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="${global.dir}/bin_data/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${global.dir}/" includes="**/*.js">
      <exclude name="*.min.js" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <echo>youcompressor for @{file}</echo> <!-- Will output each file and help debugging -->
    <exec executable="yuicompressor"> <!-- I took the args from the official documentation-->
      <arg value="--type=js" />
      <arg value="-o" />
      <arg value="'.js$:-min.js'" />
      <arg value="@{file}" />
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: @KrisErickson - If it's possible, could you please post the modifications that you had to make?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this option:

> -v, --verbose
>        Display informational messages and warnings.

There is a nice entry in the documentation for a cases like yours:

> Don't hesitate to use the -v option. Although not a replacement for
>   JSLint, it will output some helpful hints when it senses that
>   something might be wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no ather option that You can try with YUI Compressor. There are few more minimizers that works quite well and do provide that kind of information. Anyway, before minimizing you should always JSLint your files - usually the errors later reported by YUIC were a little bit on a dumb side...

Comment: We do JSHint them, and there is no errors from that.  I think that there must be a way for ant to echo the file before running it through YUI, but I don't know enough about ant.

Comment: Oh, so you're not merging the files together? Well, in order to list files you would have to modify the executable or the plugin, as I don't see any option to list the file being processed by the executable. Me, personally, I'm doing it different way, meaning I'm putting all the JS files together as one and the run compresson on top of it. If it's spits out a line number with an error, I just go and investigate that line...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
<apply … verbose="true">
```

> Whether to print a summary after execution or not. Since Ant 1.6.

Ideally it would print a statement *before* attempting to execute on the file, but having a summary afterwards at least lets you see the last successful file, which should point you to the broken file as the filesets are usually alphanumerically sequenced.

Comment: This only gives me `[apply] Applied java to 163 files and 0 directories.` still no filename