# Echo file name during ant process

Tags: javascript, css, ant, yui

I am currently using YUI compressor during an ant build process to minify CSS and JavaScript files. Whilst is it minifying each file, I would like it to output the name of the file it is currently trying to apply the executable to so that if an error occurs, I know which file has cause the error. For instance:

```
[echo] Minifying JS files...
[echo] Trying to minify file1.js...
[echo] Trying to minify file2.js....
```

Every solution I have seen seems to just echo all of the filename within the fileset after the the apply instruction has been applied to all of the files.

My ant build currently looks like this:

```
<target name="minifyJS" depends="overwriteCSSWithMinified">
    <echo message="minifying js files and saving them to fileName-min.js" />
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="${toWebHome}">
        <fileset dir="${toWebHome}">
            <exclude name="**/*.min.js" />
            <include name="**/*.js"/>
         </fileset>
         <arg line="-jar"/>
         <arg path="yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
         <arg line="-v"/>
         <srcfile/>
         <arg line="-o"/>
         <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*-min.js"/>
         <targetfile/>
     </apply>
 </target>
```

Maybe there is another way of doing this so rather than using a fileset, use an instruction that loops through every file one at a time and performs the apply on the file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454014/determine-which-file-has-an-error-when-running-yui-compressor-from-ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need to include [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net). Then you can do this:

```
<target name="minifyJS" depends="overwriteCSSWithMinified">
    <echo message="minifying js files and saving them to fileName-min.js" />
    <foreach target="yui" param="jsFile">
        <fileset dir="${toWebHome}">
            <exclude name="**/*.min.js" />  
                     <!-- should this be -min.js instead of .min.js ? -->
            <include name="**/*.js"/>
        </fileset>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="yui">
    <echo message="${jsFile}"/>
    <exec executable="java">
        <arg value="-jar"/>
        <arg value="yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
        <arg value="-v"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg value="'.js$:-min.js'"/>
        <arg value="${jsFile}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```